# ERROR : Stack Deletion Failed: AWSEBRDSDatabase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I wanted to delete an ASP.NET MVC application on the Elastic Beanstalk. But before deleting the app I first deleted the RDS server instance linked to the application. The RDS instance got deleted succesfully but now when I try to delete the Elastic Beanstalk application I get the following error message in the console -

Stack deletion failed: The following resources failed to delete AWSEBRDSDatabase

How do I proceed to delete this? I am not able to find any help regarding this issue!

Comment: got same problem.

Answer (score 7):

ran across the same issue myself today.. there doesn't appear to be a way to delink the deleted RDS instance in the Elastic Beanstalk configuration sadly. I did however manage to delete the application though by first recreating the RDS instance using the same name as before.

Go to AWS RDS > Intances > Launch DB Instance

recreate the deleted instance using the exact name that was previously used. Once successfully created, go back to Elastic Beanstalk and it allows you to terminate the environment. Bit of a pain but works none the less.

Thanks
TJ

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me and the way I was able to resume the removal of Elasticbeanstalk sucked on this status was to go through CloudFormation panel and remove the stack with failed status as described on: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-delete-failed/

After that I was able to remove the Environment and Application under Elasticbeanstalk.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error "The following resource(s) failed to delete: [AWSEBRDSDatabase]" this helped me to resolve the problem.

1. Open the AWS CloudFormation console.
2. Choose the stack that's stuck in DELETE_FAILED status.
3. Choose Delete.
   Note: A window opens and lists the resources that failed to delete.

**4. In the window, select all the resources that you want to retain, and then choose Delete stack.**

I checked to retain resource, even though the resource that was retained didn't exist but it helped me to delete it, if I didn't check it it was not deleted

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-delete-failed/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-deleted-rds-database/